# How to use v-select label in b-table and code of v-select for backend purpose

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I want to use the v-select :options="[{label: 'Canada', code: 'ca'}]" v-model="country" and use the label of this v-model in b-table and code for sending to backend.

Comment: what is  the issue youre getting ?

Comment: can you post your existing code